# Does MySQL have a constant for the maximum integer value of an Int type column?

Tags: mysql, int, max, constants, col

I have a query in my php code that I use to retrieve the rows that populate a table in my web-site, which when I want to retrieve all lines, I use the following:

```
HAVING COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )   <= 4294967295
   AND COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )   <= 4294967295
   AND COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) <= 4294967295
```

but instead of 4294957295, I'd prefer to use a constant, something like MAXINT. The query I'm using isn't in a stored procedure, so I can't just declare a local 'constant' and use its name in my query.  Alternatively, I could substitute in a value using php, but ...

Does MySQL have its own constant so I don't have to know this value to use it in my queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Neither the literal value on the RHS of your inequalities nor the maximum number of records is limited by 4294967295.  Can you explain better what the issue is here?

Comment: *but instead of 4294957295, I'd prefer to use a constant, something like MAXINT.* Not exists. At least because integers may be signed...

Comment: Tim - thanks for your reply, It's not maximum records as implied, but total count that i'm looking for, I'd have used SUM instead, but each record  in track_votes,track_sales,and track_listens represents one vote, so I used the simpler COUNT instead of SUM.  What I'm doing with this code is setting an upper threshold of votes for each category so that none of rows are eliminated.  I'd have used infinity instead of MAX Int, if I could.  Later on when this code is called again a lower value is used so that only those rows below the new threshold are included.

Comment: Akina - thanks for your reply.  Too bad, I had hoped that a constant did exist.  Given your reason, I assume that there isn't one for infinity, either.